# Can changing the topology of surface water initially hits change how much it splashes?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, fluid

I am designing a crude funnel to feed into a portable dishwasher. I was not allowed to attach to water lines so I am stuck with pouring 1.5 large pitchers of water into it. I am designing a funnel to help make that easier and quicker. One thing I realized I didnt know is if I should play with the topology to minimize splash.

I am trying to make a section where the water initially hits before going into the funnel.

If I were pouring a marble or for that matter pouring a laminar stream of water I can reason about what topology would make the water bounce more to the sides than out. However my pitcher of water acts nothing like that.

So the question is essentially: could I design a macro sized surface that a crude 3D printer could print that could be used in liu of a flat or slightly slanted flat surface to minimize or at all decrease splash from the pitcher pouring into it? How deep should the surface indentations be? How spaced apart?

Keeping in mind. If I were able to make say triangles 1" high in liu of a flat surface I could also just move said flat surface down 1" and have higher walls.

[image: Crude image of a triangular, circular, and flat option]

Comment: So make some examples and test, gauze, grills or mesh of various sizes, funnels with deep or shallow cones and varying diameter. Should be interesting.

Comment: looks like they make "anti splash funnels". the mesh seems to decelerate the flow (not 100% sure that is the essence of it tho), and the guard blocks/catches what spashback results

Comment: the idea with the triangles might have merit too... would guess one or more grilles with triangular cross section and acute angle ... something in part analogous to shapes used to construct anechoic chambers

Comment: cut the bottom from a 2 L soft drink bottle and turn upside down

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the vessel have a spiraling ramp sloping down on the side to convert the vertical flow of the water to a rotating whirlpool to convert potential energy to torque!

This way you minimize splash and noise!